# Can i open Facebook app or new Chrome window from InAppBrowser?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

Is it possible to open new Chrome window from InAppBrowser when option _blank is used?

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,hide=yes,zoom=no');
```

I added attribute target="_blank" to all links on the page, but this wouldn't open a new window.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the InAppBrowser you can call urls and you can show, depending of your platform, some files in there.

There is no way to just «start» another app, but you can:

1. Open a file with another app. Therefore you need a plugin. An overview you can get here:

http://plugreg.com/search?q=open
http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=intent

If you want to open an external url, read this:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html

2. You can share content out of your app. Therefore you also need a plugin, use this one:

http://plugreg.com/plugin/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.open instead of cordova.InAppBrowser.open

I have been using window.open without issues in my Hybrid app

There is no need to add _blank as this is the default setting..